# Upgrade in Bundle or MSI?

Tags: wix

I am completely new to WIX but I have been using Installshield for the last many years.  I am rewriting our install with WIX now and have most of the parts working in my msi.  I am now starting on the Bundle part to install the 3 prerequisites that we need, .Net framework, VC runtime, and AccessExcel.

I am getting stumped with 1 concept (so far!)  I don't think I want the Bundle in ARP but I do want the 3 redists and our MSI.  I am currently disabling the Modify/Repair/Remove in the Bundle and then running the msi with DisplayInternalUI and Visible to yes.

My question is, is this the best way to do this?  I am then having the MSI handle the major upgrades and the EULA.  I need to rebuild this msi 3 times for each deploy with different parameters passed in, so I wind up with 3 different Bundles.  Each one of the Bundles should be able to be run and completely replace the other ones.  I have always handled that in Installshield with the MajorUpdates and using the same Upgrade code in each build.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation - tired of IS and switching to Wix. I've been looking into bundling and came to the conclusion that when using burn, the bundle becomes your install package, not the msi. That is the concept I had to overcome  - which means I had to rewire my brain and focus on the bundle. I'm now thinking of the msi files as similar to merge modules (conceptually, only).

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21420776/1803823